# Getting rid of borders in Bootstrap input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The question is short: how do I get rid of the this grey borders around the Bootstrap input element [in this example ?](https://jsfiddle.net/tjw21xf3/) I am completely helpless after trying hundreds of variants in my css.

I only succeeded by including `box-shadow: none;`, but this option not only removes borders, but also the blue glowing effect when the element gets focus. I DO want this effect to stay!

HTML:

```
<table class = 'form table  zeon zeon-row-hover'>
  <thead>
    <th>My column A</th>
    <th>My column B</th>
    <th>My column C</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Smokey</td>
    <td class='zeon_input_table_cell'>
      <input class="form-control input-sm" value="8.0" />
    </td>
    <td>Brown</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rey</td>
    <td class='zeon_input_table_cell'>
      <input class="form-control input-sm" value="8.0" />
    </td>
    <td>Poe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sting</td>
    <td class='zeon_input_table_cell'>
      <input class="form-control input-sm" value="8.0" />
    </td>
    <td>Iglesias</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.zeon tbody tr td
{
    color:rgb(103, 130, 158);
    font-size:12;
    border:none;
}

table.zeon tbody tr td.zeon_input_table_cell
{
    padding: 0;
    border:none;
}

    td.zeon_input_table_cell input
{
    display:table-cell; 
    width:100%; 
    border:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
  border-color: red;
}

td.zeon_input_table_cell .form-control {
    border: 0;
    /* If I write "box-shadow: none;", borders go away, but I like the blue color when the input
    is selected and I DO want this effect to stay */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *"border"* comes from `.form-control`'s `box-shadow` value, se set it to `none` and it won't show.

```
.form-control{
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

As for *"but I like the blue color when the input is selected and I DO want this effect to stay"* - that's "triggered" on the `input:focus` state, so it will stay if you remove the `box-shadow` due the CSS specificity .

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,0.6);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjw21xf3/1/)

You probably have an issue due the [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), so be careful with your selectors. Here's also a [good online CSS specificity calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) to check your selectors.

Comment: Vucko, one minor request, could please explain how to I narrow the .form-control selector so that it applies only to those controls that are within td.zeon_input_table_cell element ? When I write td.zeon_input_table_cell .form-control, the borders goes away, BUT the shadow goes away as well :(

Comment: I've updated the question - it's due the CSS specificity, as `td.foo` is more specific then `.foo:active`. You can use `td.zeon_input_table_cell .form-control`, but then you also have to use `td.zeon_input_table_cell .form-control:focus` to return those _blue borders_, as the first selector overrides the bootstraps default one.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted